# Match time, Concatenate to datetime, and store as datetime column in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

I ran into a weird issue today. Please help figuring out the `FirstTimeReported` column. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e9845/1

Table columns:

```
SupportID int primary key, 
DateEntered datetime, 
ReportedTime varchar(4)
```

Input data

```
SupportID   DateEntered               ReportedTime
1001        2015-04-13 09:15:00       0900
2001        2015-04-14 00:10:00       2355
```

Expected results:

```
SupportID     FirstTimeReported
1001          2015-04-13 09:00:00
2001          2015-04-13 23:55:00
```

Update: Here is the Working solution 2 that I just modified from @Dan Guzman's code:

```
SELECT
      SupportID
    , CASE 
        WHEN DATEADD(minute, CAST(RIGHT(ReportedTime, 2) AS int), DATEADD(hour, CAST(LEFT(ReportedTime, 2) AS int), CAST(CAST(DateEntered AS date) AS datetime))) <= DateEntered THEN DATEADD(minute, CAST(RIGHT(ReportedTime, 2) AS int), DATEADD(hour, CAST(LEFT(ReportedTime, 2) AS int), CAST(CAST(DateEntered AS date) AS datetime)))
        ELSE DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(minute, CAST(RIGHT(ReportedTime, 2) AS int), DATEADD(hour, CAST(LEFT(ReportedTime, 2) AS int), CAST(CAST(DateEntered AS date) AS datetime)))) 
      END AS FirstTimeReported
FROM SupportContacts;
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use update and insert function so I just have to figure out with a select statement. I can get the FirstTimeReported for SupportID 1001 since I can just strip the time from DateEntered and concatenate time from ReportedTime. For SupportID 2001, the issue arise because of the midnight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the calculated FirstTimeReported should be in the past, derived from the DateEntered.  This assumes of course that the row is entered within 24 hours of the ReportTime.

```
WITH
    SupportContactsFirstTimeReported AS (
        SELECT 
              SupportID
            , DateEntered
            , DATEADD(minute, CAST(RIGHT(ReportedTime, 2) AS int), DATEADD(hour, CAST(LEFT(ReportedTime, 2) AS int), CAST(CAST(DateEntered AS date) AS datetime))) AS CalculatedReportedTime
        FROM supportContacts
    )
SELECT
      SupportID
    , CASE 
        WHEN CalculatedReportedTime <= DateEntered THEN CalculatedReportedTime
        ELSE DATEADD(day, -1, CalculatedReportedTime) 
      END AS FirstTimeReported
FROM SupportContactsFirstTimeReported;
```

Comment: Your assumptions are right based on what I have understood from the end users so far. Let me try your code and will update you soon. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If the DateEntered could be more than 24 hours after the ReportedTime, there is no solution with this data.  The best approach is to make ReportedTime a datetime column, containing the full date and time of the incident.  That will improve both performance and data integrity.

Comment: Dan Guzman! I have other inner join that I need to include before "WITH" statement in your code. How do I include join on top of "WITH" here?Thank you so much for your code.

Comment: @sky_limit, you can add the join to either the final `SELECT` statement or to the `SELECT` inside the CTE expression.

Comment: Awesome. You are the best. Very grateful to you. Bye.